# LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, a[10], b[10], n, k;
    printf("\nEnter number of sample cases:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (k = 0; k<n; k++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter frame height and width:");
        scanf_s("%d %d", &a[k], &b[k]);
    }
    for (k = 0; k<n; k++, printf("\n\n"))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a[k]; i++, printf("\n"))
            for (j = 0; j < b[k]; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == a[k] - 1)
                    printf("*");
                else if (j == 0 || j == b[k] - 1)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(".");
            }
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to build the program in visual studio 15 it gives this error.
But when i try to run the same program in dev c++, there is no error.

Comment: Do you have more information, e.g. the list of multiply defined symbols?

Comment: Try `getch();` instead of `_getch();`

Comment: Works fine here (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3).